# Resources in simpy

Tags: python, simpy

Can someone get me started on a simpy simulation?  I'm new to simpy and finding the coding very difficult.  Here's the scenario:

Jobs run in factory with different workflows.
The workflows defines which machines are used.  The machines are not the same.
Operator needs run several machines -- keeping machines busy whenever jobs are available.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should start by working through the [tutorial](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/simpy_intro/index.html) and playing with the [examples](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/index.html).

Next, start modeling and implementing a minimal example. If everything works, gradually extend your code or throw it away and restart, if you went into the wrong direction.

Take a look at the [topical guides](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topical_guides/index.html) (there are still some guides missing, but they'll be there soon) and use the [API reference](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference/index.html).

If the documentation doesn't help you, get in touch with the community via the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/simpy-users).

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading the documentation and a few [examples](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/index.html). However, some key functionality you may want to consider in the documentation is:

```
class Machine(env):
     products = simpy.resouce(env, capacity=10) // 10 products for Machine1
    # any other properties and functions you want a machine to have

class Consumer(env, machine1):
    simpy.process(ConsumeProduct(env, machine1.products))
    def ConsumeProduct(env, machine1):
        #yield machine1.request() #waits for the resource to free up
```

The above should get you started. You should be able to make many different machines, with a certain amount of similar resources. Then you will create a bunch of consumers in a loop which will request from the machine resource and `Simpy` will manage the queuing for you. This allows you to contain the madness a bit when you introduce `OOP` in junction with `Simpy`.